# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0         10
Users destroyed                                   9          0
Users deleted                                     1          0
Users contacted                                   2          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           444        320
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               26         24
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        419        449
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              318        816
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue             1,362      2,670
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              226        632
Tags merged                                      17          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             5          1
Tag synonyms created                              6          0
Questions reopened                               14          0
Questions protected                              30        132
Questions migrated                                7          0
Questions merged                                  2          0
Questions flagged⁴                               15         92
Questions closed                                312         65
Question flags handled⁴                          83         24
Posts unlocked                                    0          4
Posts undeleted                                  13         23
Posts locked                                      1         77
Posts deleted⁵                                1,300        742
Posts bumped                                      0      4,305
Escalations to the CM team                        1          0
Comments flagged                                120        539
Comments deleted⁶                               460        870
Comment flags handled                           318        341
Answers flagged                                 161      1,989
Answer flags handled                          2,019        131
All comments on a post moved to chat              5          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...